# STM32/ESP32/PIC32 + multiple SPI devices + Ethernet

Tags: stm32, adc, pic, dma

I am developing a measurement system, comprised of a MCU (being STM, ESP or PIC), multiple (let's say 8) ADCs sending data over SPI. ADCs are to be triggered using a SYNC signal so that they sample at the same time. It's crucial to access the data at the same time (or almost at the same time), the sampling frequency will be 1 or 2 kHz. I'm wondering how should I approach this: use a single physical SPI bus, and perhaps a DMA, or get a MCU with 8 physical SPI buses allowing them to operate in parallel? Additionally, I would like this MCU to support Ethernet connection, to send the data to a post-processing unit.

Comment: If they're all sampled at the same time it shouldn't really matter whether or not you read the samples out "at the same time" or not - as long as you've read them out before the next samples are taken.

Comment: I'd even debate the "sampled at the same time" requirement (particularly for something sampling that slowly), since in many cases if that really makes a difference then you're probably not anti-alias filtering properly ...

Comment: You can have STM32 chips with a couple of built in ADCs capable of sampling at 1-2 MHz. Does that fill the requirement of sampling almost simultaneously? Also can you tell how DMA would fit in, it does not really change anything.

Comment: So you think it's not worth going for a MCU with multiple SPI buses? And I should rather stick to 1 bus, and this will be enough at these speeds?